# Error processing GroovyPageView: Unknown JSP tag in gsp grails

Tags: grails, birt, jsp-tags, tld

I have read a lot of solutions here but none solved mine.
I have added the ff:

in my gsp-   `<%@ taglib prefix="gd" uri="/web-app/WEB-INF/tld/birt.tld" %>`

in my config.groovy.  - `grails.gsp.tldScanPattern='classpath*:/META-INF/*.tld,/WEB-INF/tld/*.tld'`.
in my Buildconfig.groovy -

```
runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
        runtime 'taglibs:standard:1.1.2'
```

I followed all notes from the documentation in using JSP tags fr [here](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#usingJSPTagLibraries)

I have copied the

> birt.tld

file to WEB-INF\tld directory
and I have

> jstl-1.1.2.jar

in my classpath
context/web-inf/lib directory

BUT NONE made the error disappear.

Pls. note that the tag in my view.gsp isn't getting an error (no red squiggly) lines under it, and when I press 'F3' it goes to birt.tld file, meaning my uri and file is correct. When I run the project and goes to view.gsp, that is when I encounter such error. Pls help. I have exhausted all possible solutions suggested in several similar threads. thanks

======================

My view.gsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="gd" uri="/web-app/WEB-INF/tld/birt.tld" %>


<html>
  <head>
    <title>Report ${id}</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
  </head>  
  <body><div class="body">
                    <g:form action="run" name="paramForm">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${id}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="rerun" value="1">
                        <g:each var="k" in="${reportParams.keySet() }">
                            <input type="hidden" name="${k}" value="${reportParams[k]}">
                        </g:each>
                    </g:form>
                <div class="nav">
                    <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="home" href="${resource(dir:'/')}">Home</g:link></span>
                    <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="list" action="list">List reports</g:link></span>
                    <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="edit" action="run" onClick="javascript:document.forms.paramForm.submit();return false;">Change Parameters</g:link></span>
                    <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="save" action="view" id="${id} " params="${reportParams}">
                        Permanent link to this Report
                    </g:link></span>
                    
                    
                 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="report">
        
        <div class="report-inner"> param page

<gd:parameterPage id="birtParmPage" name="myBirtParmPage" reportDesign="helloWorld.rptdesign" isCustom="true" pattern="frameset">

Select 
<gd:paramDef id="10" name="STATE" />
<br><br>
Select City
<gd:paramDef id="11" name="CITY" />
<br><br> 
Select customer
<gd:paramDef id="12" name="CUSTOMER" />
<br><br> 
    <g:submitButton class="save" name="run" value="View Report" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</gd:parameterPage>
${reportContent}
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my web.xml

```
 <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/birt.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/web-app/WEB-INF/tld/birt.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
```

buildconfig.groovy

```
 dependencies {
      ...
        runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
        runtime 'taglibs:standard:1.1.2'
        runtime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.185'
        
        compile 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.10.0.v20140318-2214'
        
        compile('org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.4.1') {
            //excludes "org.milyn", "flute", "xmlbeans", "xerces"
            excludes 'eclipse.core.runtime','flute', 'xmlbeans'
        }
    }
```

birt.tld was downloaded fr [here](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/svn/fenix/tags/release_0_0_6/fenix-birt/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tlds/birt.tld)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and solved it by importing taglib like this:

`<%@ taglib prefix="birt" uri="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/taglibs/birt.tld"  %>`

`uri` attribute should match `<uri>` tag that is inside `birt.tld`